# "You have x hours to award the bounty" when there are no answers

Tags: feature-request, bounties

Since a bounty [does not necessarily result in any answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505030/how-to-tell-pex-not-to-stub-an-abstract-class-that-has-concrete-implementations), should the prompt

> This question had a bounty worth +*X* reputation from *Whomever* that ended *Y* hours ago; you have *(24 - Y)* hours to award the bounty

even be there on questions with no answers to award to?

Comment: Now if there is ever a situation where the bounty should be refunded, that's it.

Comment: @agf Well, I *did* get three question upvotes out of it.  Still not 100 rep, but not nothing, either.  Of course, with SO being [the official forum of the product](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/), one would hope for a little more response...

Comment: And at least one pity vote for having linked to the question from this meta post.

Comment: The message could still be useful if it were possible to award the bounty to new answers that come in within this period.  Though the message should be changed.

Comment: @JeffMercado Is it possible to award the bounty to answers up to 24 hours "late?"  I actually don't know.

Comment: Nope, you cannot award the bounty to answers that are posted in the 24 hour grace period.

Comment: OK, now it just looks like people are performing a "vigilante partial refund" of the bounty by continuing to upvote the question.  If I were a better man, I'd unlink the question.  I'm not, so I won't.  Pex _is_ a pretty cool tool, though -- worth your time if you work in the .NET realm and have a way to get licensing (MSDN or academic).  So, if you're going to upvote, at least [go see what Pex is about](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/pex/).

Comment: More generally: [Explain auto-award after “you have X hours to award the bounty”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/111926)

Comment: Q: What's worse than "1 answers"? A: "0 answers".

Comment: Current the notice has a form **"This bounty has ended. Answers that other users post to this question are eligible for a +X reputation bounty. You have (24 - Y) hours to award this bounty to an eligible answer."** but the meaning of the situation is the same.

Comment: Just FYI to anyone reading this, Arjan's comment above that bounties cannot be awarded to answers posted during the grace period is **incorrect** - bounties *can* be awarded to such answers. (cc @αλεχολυτ)