# Explain auto-award after “you have X hours to award the bounty”

Tags: feature-request, bounties

In spite of the information in the [privilege page linked by the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties), what happens if you don't manually award a bounty is often unclear in the minds of awarders ([1](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/903/what-happens-if-no-one-answers-a-bounty), [2](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256/is-there-a-way-not-to-award-a-bounty), …).

At the moment, even after the bounty period has expired, the message to the bounty setter just reads “you have X hours to award the bounty”. Please explain what would happen in this specific case if the bounty setter does not manually award the bounty:

- “otherwise the amount will be lost.”
- “otherwise it will be automatically awarded to [this answer](link).”
- “otherwise half the amount will be automatically awarded to [this answer](link).”
- [No message at all if no answer was posted by the end of the bounty period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108370/you-have-x-hours-to-award-the-bounty-when-there-are-no-answers)

[image: The automatic (award) unicorn thanks you.]

Comment: How do you plan on doing that without cluttering the UI?

Comment: Adding one sentence after “you have X hours” would be clutter? “If you do not award the bounty,” could even be shortened to “otherwise”.

Comment: If you have a bounty on any question, please open up firebug or some other in-place editor (or use `javascript:document.body.contentEditable='true';document.designMode='on';void 0` to enable page editing) then play around with the page and make an example and screenshot it.  This would help your proposal greatly, people seeing it not being cluttery.  I would do it, but I have no bounties; and no Rep to spare :/